# How to count text file string length and perform the check in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

In a text file I have number of lines, and each line is a string. I need to run a check for each line/string until it finds one that is longer than 15 characters. When it finds one it should show a `MsgBox` and end the loop. As understand I need to use a Do until EOF loop, but can't make check to work.

```
Sub OpenFileAsText()
Dim FilePath As String

    FilePath = "C:\Users\Default\Desktop\test.csv"
    Open FilePath For Input As #1
    row_number = 0

        Loop Until EOF(1)
         Line Input #1, LineFromFile

        'cant work out the code to do the check

   row_number = row_number + 1
   Loop
   Close #1
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How About this?

```
Sub Sample()
    Const SEARCH_STRING As String = "SearchThis"

    Dim filename As String
    filename = "C:\Users\Default\Desktop\test.csv"

    Dim file As Integer
    file = FreeFile
    Open filename For Input As #file

    Dim rowNumber As Long
    rowNumber = 0

    Dim match As String
    Do Until EOF(file)
        rowNumber = rowNumber + 1

        Dim line As String
        Line Input #file, line

        If InStr(line, SEARCH_STRING) > 0 Then
            match = line
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    Close #file

    If match <> vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Found '" & SEARCH_STRING & "' in line #" & rowNumber & ": " & match, vbInformation, "Result"
    Else
        MsgBox "Did not find '" & SEARCH_STRING & "'", vbInformation, "Result"
    End If
End Sub
```

Explanation:

In the top of the procedure I defined a constant `SEARCH_STRING` with the string you may want to search for in the file.

Then in the `Do Until` loop `If InStr(line, SEARCH_STRING) > 0` checks if the read line contains the searched string.

`Instr` returns the position of a substring in a string. If it is not found it returns 0.

If the string has been found, it is stored in the string variable `match` and the loop is exited by `Exit Do`

Afterwards `match` will be checked, if it contains a value, and regarding to this some information will be posted by a message box.

Comment: Your contribution would be more valuable if you would edit it to include an explanation about why/how your suggestion answers the question.

Comment: I thought the code would be self explaining enough, but you are right. I added an explanation now.

Comment: Looks great, but I'm looking for any sring longer than 15 character, otherwise it can't fit on printed label. Would be posible to take constant out and insded use a Len function?

Comment: @CindyMeister: I Added some explanation now.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2: Good idea, thx. I'm not so experienced with that yet. ;-)

Comment: By the way: I'm not sure if I targeted the correct Cindy Meister because of the blank...

Comment: @Edvardas: Yes, the constant generally can be replaced by something else. But I'm not sure if I understand you correctly regarding `but I'm looking for any sring longer than 15 character`. Could you explain in detail what exactly you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for head start. This code does what I need.

```
Sub Sample()


    Dim filename As String
    filename = "C:\Users\Default\Desktop\339734.csv"

    Dim file As Integer
    file = FreeFile
    Open filename For Input As #file

    Dim rowNumber As Long
    rowNumber = 0

    Dim match As String
    Do Until EOF(file)
        rowNumber = rowNumber + 1

        Dim line As String
        Line Input #file, line

        If Len(line) > 15 Then
            match = line
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    Close #file

    If match <> vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Found"
    Else
        MsgBox "Did not find"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Fine that you got it.

Answer (score 0):

@Edvardas:
If you are interested in being informed about all lines that are too long, you can use this:

```
Sub Sample()
    Const MAX_LINE_LENGTH As Integer = 15

    Dim filename As String
    filename = "C:\Users\Default\Desktop\339734.csv"

    Dim file As Integer
    file = FreeFile
    Open filename For Input As #file

    Dim lineNumber As Long
    lineNumber = 0

    Dim matchingLines As String

    Do Until EOF(file)
        lineNumber = lineNumber + 1

        Dim line As String
        Line Input #file, line

        If Len(line) > MAX_LINE_LENGTH Then
            ' Concatenate every found line number to a string
            matchingLines = matchingLines & CStr(lineNumber) & ", "
        End If
    Loop

    Close #file

    ' Check if any line has been found
    If Len(matchingLines) > 0 Then
        ' Remove the last ", ".
        matchingLines = Left(matchingLines, Len(matchingLines) - 2)
        MsgBox "Found those lines: " & matchingLines
    Else
        MsgBox "Did not find any"
    End If
End Sub
```